# How to reverse the effect of toString() for a number?

Tags: javascript, numbers, reverse, tostring

In my website that I am making, I needed to get the scrollLeft value (jQuery, of course) and I needed to get rid of the "px" labeling. So I changed the number into a string and go rid of the "px" labeling like this: `var widththis=widther.replace(/[px]/g, "");` So I found out that if I add this number to another, it will appear like this: `1001366` Is there any way to reverse the effect of toString effect? I would love to be able to do this is plain javascript, but jQuery would be fine too. Please also include an example as well if possible. 

Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var number = parseInt('10000', 10);
```

Try the above

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: `parseInt()` should always be given the second parameter for the radix `parseInt(str, 10)`.

Comment: How would I use this to add the numbers? The link didn't really help.

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding your question, but the above will turn a numeric string into an integer.

Comment: @TGH Nevermind. That actually did work! I just didn't try it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You may use like this:

```
var widththis=widther.replace(/[px]/g, "");

+widththis + anothervar // + prefix added to convert into a number
```

Comment: Why `~~` instead of just `+`?

Comment: True, but note that `~~` converts the value to an **integer**, while a simple `+` prefix converts to a JavaScript number.

Comment: To use this, can I put `~~widththis + anothervar` into a variable?